# Is it a bad idea to switch from using a quartz oscillator for my timing circuit to using a MEMS oscillator?

Tags: pcb-design, oscillator, circuit-design, timing-analysis, mems

I've read MEMS oscillators offer improved performance including phase jitter less than 500fs and frequency stability down to +-0.1ppm. It's difficult to switch from quartz because it simply works and redesign is a bit of a pain, but wondering if anyone has made the switch and what their experience was.

I have a heart rate monitor application circuit. It's powered with a 2.5V coin cell battery and I need an oscillator as my RTC driving my MCU at a 32kHz frequency. I came across a SiTime product SIT1566 with +-5ppm frequency stability, which is key for me. The power consumption is 4.5uA, which is within my power budget. My other option is to use an AVX quartz oscillator that can achieve similar performance. It would be my first time playing with a MEMS oscillator. Any ideas on what would be the best choice from your experience?

Here's the datasheet for SIT1566: http://www.sitime.com/products/32-khz-temperature-compensated-oscillators-tcxo/sit1566

Here's the AVX quartz product datasheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/40/kt3225t_e-838149.pdf

Comment: If you need the performance, you need to do the switch. If you don't need the performance, then the switch is a waste of time.

Comment: What are you using the frequency for?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on application, and you have provided no details of your application...

Comment: I have a heart rate monitor application circuit. It's powered with a 2.5V coin cell battery and I need an oscillator as my RTC driving my MCU at a 32kHz frequency. I came across a SiTime product SIT1562 with +-5ppm frequency stability, which is key for me. The power consumption is 4.5uA, which is within my power budget. My other option is to use an AVX quartz oscillator that can achieve similar performance. It would be my first time playing with a MEMS oscillator. Any ideas on what would be the best choice from your experience?

Comment: @JavierSolorzano please provide the additional context in the question main text (use the edit button). For better reference, please also provide links to the datasheets of the components you are using and considering.

Comment: From what you say, it sounds like you have a working solution. Why change it? The MEMS solution is not cheaper, is it?

Comment: No way do you need more accuracy for a heart monitor

Comment: @dim, contriving then mocking is not what the forum's for.

Comment: @JavierSolorzano In the future, here is some help on how to write good quetions, this one is kind of broad which is why you have been experiencing "flak" from the community. Another requirement is that you educate yourself by doing research before posting. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I've replaced a quartz oscillator module with a MEMS module and it was a straightforward transition. So the technology change should present no problems.

It's hard to see how the accuracy of the quartz oscillator won't be sufficient for the heart monitor, which are measuring a pattern less than 4 Hz. If you have more information to post on this, please do.

Otherwise, the crystal oscillator will be perfectly sufficient.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'm going to work with my MEMS oscillator and see how that goes. Thanks again.

Comment: @JavierSolorzano, good luck with it. There was a kit in Farnell with a couple of devices and the programmer, if I remember rightly, you've probably seen that already.